# Unable to set up NAT/Public IP screensharing for Mac

Tags: mac, network, wifi, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I will be flying overseas soon and need to connect to my intel mac running at home, but I'm facing some troubles setting up an [NAT/public IP based screensharing](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/guide/remote-desktop/apd78601556/mac)

I have set up port forwarding on my router with TCP/UDP for ports 5900 and 3283 according to this article above, and enabled screensharing on my intel mac, but nevertheless still receive

"Make sure Screen Sharing or Remote Management (in the Sharing section of System Settings) is enabled on the remote computer."

when I try to connect. Any clues? Could it be my service provider doesn't allow such connection? I am based in Singapore and my router is a Google home

I have also tried restarting everything possible, my client mac, my intel mac, my router.

Comment: Just to confirm - you are testing this from an external connection, not your home LAN? From the same LAN it needs the router to be capable of [hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_hairpinning)

Comment: Thanks for the insight! And yes, I tried it after connecting my client mac to personal hotspot